# how to correctly pass a value to an included function?

Tags: julia

I have 2 julia files, alpha.jl and beta.jl.

in alpha.jl, there are 2 functions:

- der that returns a derivative using Zygote,
- derPlot that plots the function as well as the derivative:

```
function der(f, x)
  y = f'(x)
  return y
end

function derPlt(der,z)
  plot(f, aspect_ratio=:equal, label="f(x)")
  g(f,x₀) = (x -> f(x₀) + f'(x₀)*(x-x₀))
  plot!(g(f,x), label="dy",color="magenta")
  xlims!(-z,z)
  ylims!(-z,z)
end
```

everything comes out fine when i call these 2 functions in beta.jl, after including the files:

```
include("alpha.jl")

f(x)=-x^2+2
x = -1.3
derPlt(der(f, x), 6)
```

[image]

However, if i directly enter in a value for the function, the plotted derivative line doesnt update; i.e, if i enter  2.0 *instead* of passing in some variable named x,

```
derPlt(der(f, 2.0), 6)
```

no change is reflected on the plot. New to Julia, trying to understand and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because in your `derPlt` function, you call

```
plot!(g(f,x),...)
```

on `x` instead of the `z` argument. The problem is then that you define a `x = -1.3`, the value of which is used inside of `derPlt`, regardless of what `z` argument you feed it.

Maybe replace that line with

```
plot!(g(f,z),...)
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is a follow up to a question I answered previously I thought I'd have to respond: Benoit is broadly speaking correct, you are running into a scoping issue here, but a few more changes are in order.

Note that your function signature is `derPlot(der, z)` but then:

1. You never actually use the `der` argument in your function body; and
2. You construct your tangent line as `g(f,x₀) = (x -> f(x₀) + f'(x₀)*(x-x₀))` - note that there's no `z` in there, only an `x`

Now where does that `x` come from? In the absence of any `x` argument being passed to your function, Julia will look for it in the global scope (outside your function). Here, you define `x = -1.3`, and when you then call `derPlt`, that's the `x` that will be used to construct your tangent, irrespective of the `z` argument you're passing.

Here's a cleaned up and working version:

```
using Plots, Zygote

function derPlt(f,z)
  plot(f, label="f(x)", aspect_ratio = :equal,
        xlims = (-5,5), ylims = (-5,5))
  g(f,x₀) = (z -> f(x₀) + f'(x₀)*(z-x₀))
  plot!(i -> g(f, z)(i), label="dy",color="magenta")
end

f(x)=-x^2+2

derPlt(f, -1.5)
```

I would encourage you to read the relevant manual section on [Scope of Variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/) to ensure you get an understanding of what's happening in your code - good luck!